# How to make gets() wait only particular time for input from STDIN in C?

Tags: c, timeout, stdin, gets

Just as title states. I have `gets(buffer)` in `while(1)` infinite loop, which stops on `gets(buffer)` and wait ad infinitum. I would like `gets(buffer)` to wait only lets say 3 seconds for input from STDIN, and than while no string is in buffer, to pass control to while again, and so on.
C is the language
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You should not use `gets` but `fgets`, because `gets` is insecure.  If your buffer is too small, you get buffer overflows.

Comment: Never use `gets`.  **NEVER** use `gets`.

Comment: Since it can't be said enough, **NEVER EVER EVER** use `gets`. **EVER**!

Answer (score 3):

The standard `gets()` function does not have a timeout capability.  The canonical
way to implement a timeout in I/O operations in C is with the [`select()` function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/select.html).

Comment: is there a way to implement select() with STDIN as socket ? and setting timeout - tv_sec - in select() for some time, to do what i would like to ?

Comment: @azrahel look at `STDIN_FILENO`